# Sending notification or SMS in response to an event Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, sms

In Xcode I want to make an app that when a certain condition is met, it will send an SMS to a predefined contact.

I am aware this is not directly possible, but what are the alternatives to make this happen?

It should send without confirmation to a pre-defined contact you have selected and have a pre-defined message

Answer (score 0):

very simple: when event happen , your handler (IBAction method) sent a message to your server (e.g. web service) to send this pre-defined message.

Comment: And my server would most likely be a paid service?